# how can i use express after an async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase

her i build my firebase and initialize it and finally was able to get the data from it but the problem was i couldnt use express.get() and json the data into the server im not sure what is the problem

```
let initializeApp = require("firebase/app");

let getAnalytics = require("firebase/analytics");

let firestore = require("firebase/firestore");

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
};

const app = initializeApp.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firestore.getFirestore();

const colRef = firestore.collection(db, "products");
async function getData() {
  const querySnap = await firestore.getDocs(colRef);
  var product = [];
  querySnap.forEach((pr) => {
    console.log(pr.data());
  });
}

const express = require("express");

const ex = express();



let data = getData().then(

  ex.get("/store", (req, res) => {

  res.json(data);
  ex.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log(data);
  })
})


);
```

i tried the code above nothing worked and got this error:

```
 debug('dispatching %s %s', req.method, req.url);
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'method')
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\hamdan\OneDrive\Desktop\hello\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:139:34)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\hamdan\OneDrive\Desktop\hello\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:181:10)
    at app (C:\Users\hamdan\OneDrive\Desktop\hello\node_modules\express\lib\express.js:39:9)
```

i tired this

```
let data = getData().then(() => {
  ex.get("/store", (req, res) => {
    res.json(data);
  });
  ex.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

it didnt give back an error but the problem is the data styed empty

Answer (score 1):

you should put your server.listen in a different scope, not inside a get request scope. Your server should start before everything.

```
ex.get("/store", (req, res) => {
  try{
   res.json(data);
}catch(error){
console.log(error)
}})
ex.listen(5000, () => {
 console.log(data);
})
```

`

```html
Try this



ex.get("/store", async(req, res) => {
  try{
 let data = await get.Data()
 console.log(data); //to see what you are recieving
   res.json(data);
}catch(error){
console.log(error)
}})
ex.listen(5000, () => {
 console.log("server running on port 5000);
})
```

Comment: it worked but the res.json(data) is giving back an empty array not sure why

Comment: maybe it's because you have to use async await to get a proper response into you endpoint when it envolves db request try to do what i wrote above and keep me updated

Comment: thank you i got it, the problem was that i forgot to do data.push(pr.data()) where i did a forEach with the querySnap